# Как сделать параметр функции generic

Tags: swift, generics

мне нужно сделать функцию которая будет принимать generic который подписан под протокол Codable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func myFunc<T: Codable>(snapshot: [String : Any], object: T.Type) {
  .... }
```